# Problems with Gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, gulp

I need your help. I`ve problems with Gulp. Idk how to fix this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKFOF.png)

I wanna reinstall gulp but I can`t delete it. I got this problem after this command

> npm i gulp --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the installation like this :

```
npm i gulp -force
```